# (Overloading) - Sobrecargar Operadores en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operador, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Como puedo sobrecargar los operadores `(+, -, *, /, ... , //)` sobre un objeto en python.

Ejemplo:

```
a = Vector(3, 5)
b = Vector(2, 7)
print(a + b)   # Output: <Vector (5.000000, 12.000000)>
print(b - a)   # Output: <Vector (-1.000000, 2.000000)>
print(b * 1.3) # Output: <Vector (2.600000, 9.100000)>
print(a // 17) # Output: <Vector (0.000000, 0.000000)>
print(a / 17)  # Output: <Vector (0.176471, 0.294118)>
```

Donde `Vector` es la clase siguiente:

```
class Vector(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Todo en Python es un objeto. Cada objeto tiene algunos métodos internos especiales que utiliza para interactuar con otros objetos. En general, estos métodos siguen la convención de nomenclatura `__action__`. En conjunto, esto se denomina [modelo de datos de Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Puede sobrecargar *cualquiera* de estos métodos. Esto se usa comúnmente en la sobrecarga del operador en Python. A continuación se muestra un ejemplo de sobrecarga del operador utilizando el modelo de datos de Python. La clase `Vector` crea un vector simple de dos variables. Añadiremos el soporte apropiado para las operaciones matemáticas de dos vectores utilizando la sobrecarga del operador.

```
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, v):
        # Sumar dos Vectores
        return Vector(self.x + v.x, self.y + v.y)

    def __sub__(self, v):
        # Restar dos Vectores
        return Vector(self.x - v.x, self.y - v.y)

    def __mul__(self, s):
        # Multiplicar un Vectores por un escalar
        return Vector(self.x * s, self.y * s)

    def __div__(self, s):
        # Dividir un vector por un escalar
        float_s = float(s)
        return Vector(self.x / float_s, self.y / float_s)

    def __floordiv__(self, s):
        # Parte entera de la divicion de un vector sobre un escalar
        return Vector(self.x // s, self.y // s)

    def __repr__(self):
        # Imprima una representación amistosa de la clase Vector. De lo contrario, sería
        # <__main__.Vector instance at 0x01DDDDC8>.
        return '<Vector (%f, %f)>' % (self.x, self.y, )

a = Vector(3, 5)
b = Vector(2, 7)
print(a + b)   # Output: <Vector (5.000000, 12.000000)>
print(b - a)   # Output: <Vector (-1.000000, 2.000000)>
print(b * 1.3) # Output: <Vector (2.600000, 9.100000)>
print(a // 17) # Output: <Vector (0.000000, 0.000000)>
print(a / 17)  # Output: <Vector (0.176471, 0.294118)>
```

**Tabla de Operadores**

A continuación se encuentran los operadores que pueden estar sobrecargados en las clases, junto con las definiciones de método que se requieren, y un ejemplo del operador en uso dentro de una expresión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencia:**
[Medium - (Overloading) — Sobrecargar Operadores en Python](https://medium.com/@LuisMBaezCo/overloading-sobrecargar-operadores-en-python-5d7a75e2bfdf)